# How Lookup For Friend Of Specified User

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

Get A List Of Friends For Specified Facebook User

Whats Permissions Must Be Asked For This ???

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for you, but fortunately for the friends of your friends, the friends method is only available on me (https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=xxx) and not on any other user (https://graph.facebook.com/id/friends)

You can try this out for yourself just in a browser, if you go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/, scroll down to the Connections section and follow the friends link, you will get the list of all your own friends (assuming you are logged into facebook)

If you then replace the 'me' in the URL you get with the id of one of your friends, you will get the following message:

"(#604) Can't lookup all friends of [id]. Can only lookup for the logged in user ([loggedinid]), or friends of the logged in user with the appropriate permission"

EDIT:

This may have changed since the last time I looked at this, the friends of the logged in user are available with the user_about_me permission, and there is a related friends permission called friends_about_me, this may let you access friends of friends. (See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Comment: thank you i am solve this problem by asking User about permission that allow me to Get His Friend List By https://graph.facebook.com/id/friends?accesstoken=xxx

Answer (score 0):

I've found it explained here [Facebook API from C# – Getting the list of friends](http://dennisdel.com/?p=185).
You have to create the tokken and then get `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token={TOKEN HERE WHITOUT {}}`

Comment: But I don't Want My Info (me) I want another User

Comment: Ups, I don't know how to do it using Facebook API. You cold try using a `WebClient`...

Answer (score -1):

well i think you should have a look at [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/friendlist/)

and i think that instead of me you can place friends id and thats all

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friendlists
```

Comment: @abhi I am honored by your down vote. At the date it was posted it had this method and later upgraded.

Comment: I am in the same boat as the OP for this question. I did discover that the graph API does not let me substitute ME with a friend's ID. It throws up a nice message when I attempt to do that.

Comment: @abhi i said that when this question was posted at that time this worked.